# Java Slick2d Image/Texture .equals()

Tags: java, image, slick2d

I am creating a 2d tile game. In this game, borders between different types of tiles are drawn in the program (corner tiles, side tiles, etc.) There is a finite number of possible tiles like this. As soon as I implemented this however, the frame rate crashed pretty badly. I figured out that the act of redrawing the 80-90 visible tiles every frame was the problem. I tried to implement a cache system to cache the unique tiles. This system works except for the fact that I cannot compare a generated image to a cache of images.

Here is what I would like to be able to do:

```
//tile object is an Image
if (cache.contains(tile)){
    return cache;
} else {
    cache.add(tile);
    return tile;
}
```

The problem lies with the comparison of two Slick2D Image objects. It seems like the `image.equals()` method will only be true if both the image pointers represent the same object. Other than pixel by pixel comparison, is there a way to quickly see if two different Image objects have exactly the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past how I have used tile systems is by using the TiledMap classes and then redrawing what the world tiles would look like in the Tiled Editor (http://www.mapeditor.org). This creates a .tmx file which can be used for collisions and rendering.

However, if you are looking for procedural generation my best recommendation would be to create a 'Tile' class. For example:

```
public class Tile {
    public static int CORNER_TILE = 0;
    public static int SIDE_TILE = 1;
    public static int CENTRE_TILE = 2;

    public int x, y, type;

    public Tile(int type, int x, int y) {
        this.type = type;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    } 
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        //Insert rendering code for each different tile type
        //For example:

        if (this.type == Tile.CENTRE_TILE) {
            g.drawImage(Main.someTileImage, x * 32, y * 32);
            //Multiply x and y by dimensions of tile
        }
   }
}
```

All you would then need is a 2d array of tiles which you loop through to update each frame. I know this isn't exactly what you asked but these are my ways of working with tiles. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up creating the tile permutations before hand and saving them to an image.